# Embedded submanifold of $\mathbb{S}^3$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let's consider $f:\mathbb{S}^3\to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x,y,z,t)=x^2+y^2-z^2-t^2$

(1) show that $M_0:= f^{-1}(0)$ is an embedded submanifold of $\mathbb{S}^3$.

(2) show that $M_0$ is diffeomorphic to the 2-torus.

(3) find all points at which $f$ is a submersion.

I have some problem with this exercise because I want to use the regular value theorem but proving that $f$ is a submersion at all points of $f^{-1}(0)$, with charts of $\mathbb{S}^3$, needs way too many calculations. How can I solve smartly this problem?

*My attempt for points (1) and (3):*

I can consider the natural extension of $f$ to $\mathbb{R}^4$ given by $\widetilde{f}: \mathbb{R}^4\to \mathbb{R}$ with $\widetilde{f}(x,y,z,t)=x^2+y^2-z^2-t^2$. Clearly $\widetilde{f}$ is a submersion at all points $p\neq 0$, so also at every $p\in \mathbb{S}^3$. Therefore, since $f=\widetilde{f}\circ \iota\mid_{\mathbb{S}^3}$, by chain rule I get, for $p\in \mathbb{S}^3$,
$$(df)_p=(d\widetilde{f})_p\circ (d\iota\mid_{\mathbb{S}^3})_p$$
where I know that $(d\widetilde{f})_p$ is surjective and $(d\iota\mid_{\mathbb{S}^3})_p$ is injective. It seems to be almost done but I don't know how to conclude.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:Let $G:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$ denote the function $G(x,y,z,t)=x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2-1$.  We have the following:

- $T_p\mathbb{S}^3=\ker dG_p$ for $p\in\mathbb{S}^3$.
- $p\in\mathbb{S}^3$ is a critical point of $f$ if and only if $T_p\mathbb{S}^3\subset\ker d\tilde{f}_p$. By dimensional consideration, this is true if and only if $T_p\mathbb{S}^3=\ker d\tilde{f}_p$.
- Two linear functionals on a vector space are constant multiples of each other if they have the same kernel.

Comment: Thank you! This explains why the critical points of $f$ are the critical points of $F$.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few ideas:

For $(1)$, I think your argument is fine. There is a (smooth) [embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-sphere) $e$ of $S^3$ in $R^4$, so using your idea of extending $f$ to $F$ defined on all of $\mathbb R^4$, one has $f=F\circ e$ and now the chain rule shows that $0$ is a regular value for $f$ and the result follows from the regular level set theorem. (Because $\textit{now}\ \mathcal J(F)$ is easy to calculate.)

For $(2)$, use the fact that $(r,s) \mapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\sin(2\pi r), \cos(2\pi r), \sin(2\pi s), \cos(2\pi s))$ maps $S^1\times S^1$ diffeomorphically into $S^3$ and show that the image is exactly $f^{-1}(0).$

For $(3)$, the points $(p,f(p)=q)$ at which $f$ is a submersion will be those for which the subset $S$ of $\mathbb R^4$ defined by $x^2+y^2-z^2-t^2=q$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2=1$ is a regular submanifold of $\mathbb R^4$ so if we define $F(x,y,z,t)=(x^2+y^2-z^2-t^2,x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2-1)$ then $S=F^{-1}(q,0)$. Now,

$$\mathcal J(F)=\begin{pmatrix}
2x &2y  &-2z  &-2t \\ 
 2x&2y  &2z  &2t 
\end{pmatrix}$$

The critical points of $F$ are the points $(x, y, z,t)$ where 
this matrix has rank $< 2$. That is, where all $2 \times 2$ minors 
are zero. So, we get the conditions

$\tag1 xz=0,\ yz=0,\ xt=0,\ yt=0$

We also have

$\tag 2 x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2-1=0$

If $x\neq 0,$ we get $x^3+xy^2-x=0\ $ so

$\tag 3 x^2+y^2=1\ $ 
If $y\neq 0$ we get the same equation.

Similarly, if either $t$ or $z\neq 0,$ then

$\tag4 z^2+t^2=1.$

Since $(3)$ and $(4)$ cannot both hold (because of $(2)$), if $(3)$ holds then $z=t=0$, while if $(4)$ holds then $x=y=0.$

But we also have

$\tag5 x^2+y^2-z^2-t^2=q$

so if $(3)$ holds then $q=1$ and if $(4)$ holds, then $q=-1.$

So, the critical points of $f$ are $A=B\cup C:=\{(x,y,z,t):x^2+y^2=1;\ t=z=0\}\cup\{t^2+z^2=1;\ x=y=0\}$ with critical values $1$ and $-1$, respectively.

edit: the proof that $f$ is a submersion goes as follows:

Let $p$ be a point on the sphere in the complement of $A$, and without loss of generality, parameterize the sphere by $\phi(x,y,z)=(x,y,z,\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2-z^2})$ in some sufficiently small open set $\phi^{-1}(p)\in U$  so that $\phi$ is a smooth bijection in $U$. (the other $2$ obvious parameterizations cover the other possibilities). Then,

$f\circ\phi(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2-z^2-(1-x^2-y^2-z^2)=-1+2x^2+2y^2$

and

$\mathcal J(f\circ \phi)=4\begin{pmatrix}
 x&y  &0
\end{pmatrix}.$

If $x=y=0$ then $t^2+z^2= 1$ and $p\in B$ so $p$ is critical. We conclude that $\mathcal J(f\circ \phi)$ has rank $1$ whenever $p\notin A$, and then so does $\mathcal J(f)$ because $\mathcal J(\phi)$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Your computation of $J(f)$ is for $f$ as a mapping with domain $\Bbb R^4$, not $S^3$. The right way to do all such problems is to consider the map $F\colon\Bbb R^4\to\Bbb R^2$ given by $F(x) = (\tilde f(x), \|x\|^2-1)$.

Comment: @Jackristin I had another crack at this. I am self-studying this material myself so your comments are welcome.

Comment: It really makes sense but why is this true: *the points $(p,f(p)=q)$ at which $f$ is a submersion will be those for which the subset $F^{-1}(q,0)$ is a regular submanifold of $\mathbb R^4$*?

Comment: I redid the calculation from scratch. I am hoping that now, it's OK!